# Penalty issue for a duplicate page in site but original page doesn't exist anymore

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I've a product page ranking well for a keyword which I duplicated from the company itself which contained faq about it's product.

Now the website has removed that page so mine is the only one existing now.

Does anyone have any idea if still duplicate content penalty will be applied to my page?

Should I go ahead and remove it?

Comment: What is the duplicate content penalty? Is there an authoritative web page where I can read about the specifics?

Comment: Nevermind, I should of searched. http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/demystifying-duplicate-content-penalty.html. From the page: There's no such thing as a "duplicate content penalty." At least, not in the way most people mean when they say that.

Comment: This is the page: http://www.creditcardpaymentgateways.in/icici-payseal-payment-gateway-faq-frequently-asked-questions.html . Since it is a "copied" product page there will be definitely some penalty. I've removed other duplicate product pages with 410 status. But this page's original source is no more. Should I keep this then?

Comment: @JMC duplicated content within your site has no penalty but from other site, yes. In fact Yahoo has simply turned blind eye to my site even though it's the unique one in targeted category. Although Google is ranking it in the middle but some unimportant and unrelated pages are ranking abovemy site.

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid duplicating content yes, but you may be looking in the wrong place regarding the reason your site isn't ranking how you want it.

Answer (score 1):

If your product page is ranking well then it obviously hasn't been flagged for duplicate content. If it was it wouldn't be ranking well or even at all. So why would you want to remove a well ranked page??

Comment: One page may be ranking well but may be overall site is getting penalized...

Comment: no this isn't question I've asked. Similar question I've raised in another post. In this question, the original source has disappeared. So at the current moment, no duplicate content is present anywhere.

Comment: The whole site won't be penalized as duplicate content doesn't cause a penalty. It just means Google may filter out pages it considers to be duplicates.

Comment: are you sure? Isn't Panda update all about penalizing duplicate content?

Comment: The Panda update removes or extremely devalues low quality content. The sites themselves do not receive a blanket penalty.